# How do I pass an object to R mtext()?

Tags: r, graphics

I make several calls to `mtext()` using the same `args`:

```
mtext(expression(bold("Exome SNP QQ Plots")), col="black", outer=TRUE, cex=1.3)
```

I want to create an object containing these `args`, that I can pass to `mtext()`, rather than recreating it each time. I tried to put the `args` above in a variable as a list:

```
PageTitle <- list(expression(bold("Exome SNP QQ Plots")), col="black", outer=TRUE, cex=1.3)
```

And then pass the variable to `mtext()`:

```
mtext(PageTitle)
```

This does not behave the same as calling `mtext()` with a complete set of args.
I suspect that `mtext()` is not looking for a list, but a different kind of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `do.call` is what you are looking for:

```
do.call(mtext, PageTitle)
```

We have the syntax `do.call(what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame())`, here `what` is a function and `args` is a **list** of arguments to the function call - and that is great that you already have this list. `do.call` is a very useful function and it might help you in other situations too.